# VueJS Axios chain request dynamic array vs static array error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Quick overview of my project:
POST request is made to 3rd party API that is creating orders (can be single or multiple orders) and then just orderId is received. In order to get order specific data and display it to user I need to do another request to another API that takes key and orderID as param and if order is found will display the order specific data. This has to happen in single request meaning that upon button click order is made and order data is also displayed(which is second request). So I need to chainrequest these 2 together.
Flow: create order -> receive IDs (array) -> make second request to receive order specific data -> Display data to user

Simplified code example (removed proper error handling etc. This is just an axios example):

```
            const axiosHeaders = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            };
           
            //APIKEY is just string example "123dsdasd1231eadsa" and array of data is arrayOfData: [ 13798, 13799, 13800 ]
            const URLparams = "key="+ this.apiKey + "&data=" + this.arrayOfData

            axios.post('http://xxxxxxxxxxx/placebulkorder', params, axiosConfig)
            .then((response) => { 

                this.orderids = response.data.data.map(data => data.order_id)
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(error)
            }).finally(() => {
                
                const params = new URLSearchParams()
                params.append('key', this.apiKey)
                params.append('orderid', this.orderids)

                axios.post('http://xxxxxxxxxxx/order-status-bulk', params, axiosConfig
                ).then((response => { console.log(response) }))
                 .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })

            })
```

**Problem**:
As stated above, in order to get order specific data, second request has to be made. This request takes apiKey and orderIds array as parameters ('Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

1. If I had static orderId: [13798, 13799, 13800] and used it in the second request URLparam then the second request returns code 200 so everything works fine.

   ```
   data(){
      return {
          orderId: [13798, 13799, 13800], //hardcoded values for example
          api_key: process.env.MIX_IPHONE_CHECKS_APP_KEY, //API key from .env file
    },
   ```

   [image]
2. If I had return data orderId: [] and in code I would map the first request response orderIds to this.orderID //dynamic array// and used it in code as shown below, then server returns error 500. (mapping is in the example above)

   ```
    data(){
      return {
          orderids: [], //used to map response orderID dynamically
          api_key: process.env.MIX_IPHONE_CHECKS_APP_KEY, //API key from .env file
    },
   ```

[image]

Using static array in URLparam will succeed but using dynamic array from first request response object will throw an error code 500. This is very strange because After first request if I console.log out the this.orderIds then all the correct response orderIDs will be displayed in the console.log meaning that the array has items in them. Also as shown above in both cases, request is identical but one produces error 500 and another succeeds.

**What have I tried?**
I have tried to not use axios.then.catch and convert it into async/await manually. Also not working.
I have tried to use QS module to stringify the urlparams (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) but also not working.
I have tried to use JSON stringify method in maping
this.orderids = response.data.data.map(data => JSON.stringify(data.order_id)) and later use .join() method to convert it into array.
All the time I get same result. Static array works but dynamic does not.

**BUT** .... I have also tried one other thing that produced somewhat an result. If I created separate method for having second request meaning:

1. click button to create orders
2. map orderIds from response to array
3. wait couple of seconds and click another button to get order specific data then it succeeds
   So in conclusion... waiting before making second request works.In case of dynamic array if I wait couple of seconds before making second request (setting timeout in finally cause or waiting before manually triggering second request) it works.
   This only applies to dynamic array. Does not matter how long the static array is.. in case of static array, api succeeds with code 200 always.

What causes this issue? Why is dynamic array handled differently? Is this axios specific thing? How to solve?

Thank you. If more specification is needed then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try using another `.then()` hook instead of relying on finally.
Here's how you could solve it and keep your current flow intact.

```
const axiosHeaders = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            };
           
            //APIKEY is just string example "123dsdasd1231eadsa" and array of data is arrayOfData: [ 13798, 13799, 13800 ]
            const URLparams = "key="+ this.apiKey + "&data=" + this.arrayOfData

            axios.post('http://xxxxxxxxxxx/placebulkorder', params, axiosConfig)
            .then((response) => { 
                return response.data.data.map(data => data.order_id)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(error)
            }).then((ids) => {
                const params = new URLSearchParams()
                params.append('key', this.apiKey)
                params.append('orderid', ids)

                axios.post('http://xxxxxxxxxxx/order-status-bulk', params, axiosConfig
                ).then((response => { console.log(response) }))
                 .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
            });
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for suggestion but the result is the same :( Error 500 is thrown

Comment: Are you certain that orderids are returned from your first call?
Syntaxwise I don't see an issue with either implementation to be honest.
Rewriting it into async/await shouldn't yield any different results either.
Currently it sounds like you execute the first call but never actually map an array of orderids (maybe an array of undefined(s)?) so on your second call it returns 500 probably due to missing params in your api call.

Comment: Hi, yes. If I console log the orderids then I can see them in the log. Also as shown on the images above, the request contains the orderid. :( it is a mystery because I have spent 20 hours at least on the issue and nothing :/

Comment: Can you check if the request is even handled by your receiving API? 
Does the issue maybe come from some "race" condition? Like you're making the order, getting an id, but the other API you're calling has not been fed the information as of your second call thus your orderids are not known at that point? it would explain why waiting helps and why a static array works as  they're probably ids of orders you already created some time ago.

Comment: Thank you Braks. This makes much much more sense what you just said tbh. What concerns me is that orderID is returned. Maybe the 3rd party system throws ID back, but on the backend the order itself is not created yet and that is why I receive error?
Also it makes sense because If I set up delay for the second request then lets assume that I create 100 orders with first request and wait 5sec and then make second request, error is thrown.. but If i create 1 order and wait 5 sec for second request, it is success. Maybe the theory is that backend isnt finished orders yet and thus the error then?

Comment: Scar-2018 yes it is backend error. But what confused me was that technically API works cause if I use static array ... response is success. Thus actually API itself works. I will contact 3rd party API partners and ask their solution for it. Because I can not complete the complete flow if they are having Race Condition